# Can't access SQL Server Instance

Tags: sql-server

i moved my website on a server, it have installed web application and SQL server instance (this site is only for private network), if i try to access sql instance from SSMS it connect without problem, but when i try to access data from my website or SSMS installed on another pc connected to the same network it's says me that instance name is not correct or firewall block sql server ports. Sql connection string is correct, both SQL Server and SQL Browser services are active, named pipes and TCP are enabled, and i've added rules to firewall to allow connection from port 1433 and 1434(this one is for UDP) but i've the same problem, any help?

Comment: have you tried to add yourself (account of the other computer on the same network)  as a sysadmin !!

Comment: @MohamedAzizi I'm using sql authentication, with sa account

Comment: Can you ping your new server from a different machine? Double check instance name of the SQL Server. It could be a named instance.

Comment: @Alex i can ping server, this server have iis, and i can open my website, but when i log in i got back a error message, i tried to create a named instance of sql server but i've the same problem